# Apache calcite:parse failed: Encountered "from \""

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-calcite

I am currently attempting to connect mysql using calcite.
However, I had problems executing SQL statements

When I use this sql to excute,it works.

> ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
>           "select * from ex.depts");

But I would like to access a table named like this "primary_test",it failed.

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while executing SQL "select * from ex.primary_test": From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 29: Object 'primary_test' not found within 'ex'
>       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
>       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
>       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:163)
>       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeQuery(AvaticaStatement.java:227)
>       at CalciteMysqlConnectionIns.main(CalciteMysqlConnectionIns.java:44)
>   Caused by: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 29: Object 'primary_test' not found within 'ex'
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:463)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:787)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:772)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.newValidationError(SqlValidatorImpl.java:4788)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.resolveImpl(IdentifierNamespace.java:166)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.IdentifierNamespace.validateImpl(IdentifierNamespace.java:177)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate(AbstractNamespace.java:84)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace(SqlValidatorImpl.java:977)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:953)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3050)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateFrom(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3032)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateSelect(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3302)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SelectNamespace.validateImpl(SelectNamespace.java:60)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.AbstractNamespace.validate(AbstractNamespace.java:84)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateNamespace(SqlValidatorImpl.java:977)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateQuery(SqlValidatorImpl.java:953)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlSelect.validate(SqlSelect.java:216)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateScopedExpression(SqlValidatorImpl.java:928)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validate(SqlValidatorImpl.java:632)
>       at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:556)
>       at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:265)
>       at org.apache.calcite.prepare.Prepare.prepareSql(Prepare.java:231)
>       at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare2_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:772)
>       at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepare_(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:636)
>       at org.apache.calcite.prepare.CalcitePrepareImpl.prepareSql(CalcitePrepareImpl.java:606)
>       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.parseQuery(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:229)
>       at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteMetaImpl.prepareAndExecute(CalciteMetaImpl.java:550)
>       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareAndExecuteInternal(AvaticaConnection.java:675)
>       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaStatement.executeInternal(AvaticaStatement.java:156)
>       ... 2 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Object 'primary_test' not found within 'ex'
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:463)
>       at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInst.ex(Resources.java:572)
>       ... 30 more

I have used many different query like

> ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
>           "select * from ex.\"primary_test\"");

but it doesn't work.
Could someone help me with this question?

my code is like following:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.calcite.adapter.jdbc.JdbcSchema;
import org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnection;
import org.apache.calcite.schema.Schema;
import org.apache.calcite.schema.SchemaPlus;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;

public class CalciteMysqlConnectionIns {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver");

    Properties info = new Properties();
    info.setProperty("lex", "JAVA");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
    CalciteConnection calciteConnection = connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
    SchemaPlus rootSchema = calciteConnection.getRootSchema();

    // 本地Schema.
    // Schema schema = ReflectiveSchema.create(calciteConnection, rootSchema, "hr",
    // new HrSchema());

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://192.168.130.7/hr");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("123456");
    Schema schema = JdbcSchema.create(rootSchema, "ex", dataSource, null, "sql_learn");

    rootSchema.add("ex", schema);
//    System.out.println(calciteConnection.getMetaData());
    DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = calciteConnection.getMetaData();
//    ResultSet rs = databaseMetaData.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[]{"TABLE"});
    Statement statement = calciteConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(
        "select * from ex.\"primary_test\"");

    output(resultSet, System.out);
    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
  }

  private static void output(ResultSet resultSet, PrintStream out) throws SQLException {
    final ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
    final int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
//    out.println(metaData.getColumnLabel(1) + " " + metaData.getColumnLabel(2));
//    out.println(metaData.getColumnTypeName(1) + " " + metaData.getColumnTypeName(2));
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      for (int i = 1; ; i++) {
        out.print(resultSet.getString(i));
        if (i < columnCount) {
          out.print(", ");
        } else {
          out.println();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
select * from ex.`primary_test`
```

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, examples, etc.